# Cisco VPN .pcf profile can't be imported in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vpnc

First import attempt after fresh installation of `network-manager-vpnc` failed with *Ubuntu 14.04 Has Experienced An Internal Error* screen.

I have tried to restart `network-manager-vpnc` and computer, import now fails without any error message.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, [recently reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-vpnc/+bug/1310928).